# Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta linea de codigo en un comando propio de Laravel, relativamente sencillo

```
User::where('nda_approved', 0)->whereRaw('(mod(DATEDIFF(`created_at`,\''.Carbon::now().'\'),7) = 0')->get();
```

Al hacer un pequeño test en Tinker, obtengo el siguiente error

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from
> `users` where `nda_approved` = 0 and
> (mod(DATEDIFF(`created_at`,'2021-02-09 12:59:09'),7) = 0)'

Sin embargo, si copio la consulta y la pego directamente en Workbench (que esta conectado a la misma base de datos)

```
select * from `users` where `nda_approved` = 0 and (mod(DATEDIFF(`created_at`,'2021-02-09 12:59:09'),7) = 0)
```

Todo funciona bien, y obtengo las filas deseadas. ¿Alguna idea de porque pasa esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta relacionado con las comillas, pues como notas en la consulta del mensaje de error tienes una comilla sencilla al final que no empata con otra al inicio:

```
09 12:59:09'),7) = 0)'
```

Mas el uso de unas diagonales (*que asumo son para tratar de escapar algo*), pero no son necesarias

Entonces para respetar y utilizar la consulta SQL que expones funciona, puedes usarla de esta forma a nivel de Laravel:

```
$fechaActual = now();

User::where('nda_approved', 0)
    ->whereRaw("mod(DATEDIFF('created_at', '$fechaActual'),7) = 0")
    ->get();
```

Por último, no necesitas invocar a la clase `Carbon` (*de manera estricta*) para acceder a sus funcionalidades, en cambio [auxiliate del helper `now()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now) que te da acceso a una instancia de *Carbon*.

Comment: Gracias! Pero cuando lo hago de esta forma, el query resultante es `select * from users where nda_approved = 0 and mod(DATEDIFF('created_at', now()),7) = 0`, entonces la parte de now() no tendria que ir concatenada como un string?

Comment: @KennyBarrera revisa si la edición te es útil